# 盃に口をつけてごまかすほど to describe a 祝杯

Tags: meaning

A person was excited for the trip tomorrow and couldn't sleep. Reflecting on why he didn't drink much at last night's party:

> こうしたとき酒が飲めれば、したたか酔うて眠ればよい。しかし祝杯すらも盃に口をつけてごまかすほどであるから、秘めたる興奮のさましようはなかった。

盃に口をつけてごまかすほど - what does this mean (e.g. does this mean that 祝杯 was small, one 口-ish size only)?

Comment: It means that 'He pretends to drink alcohol because he can't drink even a toast at all.'

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence indicates that the writer cannot drink. Then in the next he goes on to describe how much of a lightweight/teetotaler he is by saying, "祝杯すらも盃に口をつけてごまかすほどである" -- his alcohol aversion is such that, even when participating in celebratory drinking of sake, he only goes through the motions of drinking by just touching his mouth to 盃!